# In Scala, how to override a method that takes a java.util.Map

Tags: java, scala, interop

The Java class I am trying to subclass has a method like:

```
public abstract void foo(Map var1);
```

I can't figure out how to override that method. The Java class I am subclassing from does not use generics.

In Scala I tried:

```
override def foo(var1:java.util.Map[Int,Int]){ }
```

But the compiler gives me the error message that it overrides nothing..

The heart of the problem is that Scala expects type parameters on the Map, however the Java class doesn't use them.

Comment: `override def foo(var1:java.util.Map[_,_]){ }`

Comment: @pedrofurla: why post an answer as a comment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is going to make it work

```
override def foo(var1:java.util.Map[_,_]){ }
```